# Should I include Entity Framework in my class library or directly into application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

You might have encountered this type of question before but in my case, it's a bit different scenario and I cannot find a feasible answer. (It might exist already, however I was not able to find one).

I'm working on a business application which has the entire functionality split into multiple class libraries. I'm using Entity Framework and I'm not sure which is the right place to include it? In my case, I've these libraries:

- Project.Library.Core
- Project.Library.Models (Contains the entity data model and entities).
- Project.Library.Auth (Contains authentication related and user management classes).
- and similar classes who frequently use the entities and the db context.

In order to make this work, I've to install Entity Framework in every library separately. Eventually they will be included in a number of ASP.NET MVC Web Applications. I'd have installed Entity Framework directly into the web apps but this application will have mobile apps in the future along with a possible windows store app. In that case, I can simply set up a ASP.NET Web API and use the existing class libraries to generate the required data. This is the only factor holding me back from incorporating Entity Framework directly into the web apps.

So what's your opinion on this? Include Entity Framework in every library separately (required to function properly) or simply include in the web app and later follow the same approach for the Web API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to "install" EntityFramework into one place: **Project.Library.Models**. Assuming standard code-first objects as your DTOs, you won't need a direct reference anywhere else as long as you wrap the context object with a Data Access Layer.

Adding a reference to that assembly will cause the requisite DLLs to be included with your apps, web sites, etc. Note that if you are using EntityFramework.SqlServer, the transient dependency won't be detected by Visual Studio so you need to do something like:

```
class Include
{
    private Include() { }
    private SqlProviderServices IncludeSql;
}
```

Somewhere in the models project so that DLL is copied over also.

Comment: I included the Models library into another dependent class library and tried to create an instance of my db context (var context = new MyDbContext();) and it says "The type DbContext is defined in an assembly which is not referenced". What could be the possible reason behind this?

Comment: @HumzaKhan You might try wrapping your DBContext in a Data Access Layer (just an object that exposes all the stuff you want to do to your database)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET is this standard way? i create separate class library for entity framework as you say but each time i change main project and compile solution,class library compile too

Comment: @AminM I wouldn't say its a "standard" way; but certainly a common one (and necessary if you want to share your model between projects). As far as recompiling; you either hit "rebuild" instead of "build" or your changes were detected as affecting the `Models` project (either models references your main project, bad, or a common library changed, or you didn't change what you think you did)

Comment: @HumzaKhan Any particular reason you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That was by mistake, I was going through my old questions!

Comment: @HumzaKhan No problem; just making sure :)